# Sub Query inside FullText Search Contains

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use Sub Query as a search term inside "Contains" of Full Text Search in sql server.
Some thing like that,

```
SELECT    TOP (1) DocumentDate, Auto_FullText
FROM      tblDocuments
WHERE     CONTAINS(Auto_FullText, (Select FirstName From tblUser Where UserId=1))
```

Unfortunately, it is not working...

Please recommend another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this but another simpler option would be something like....

Declare a variable store the value into this variable and pass this variable to your contains clause in your FTS query

```
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(100);

SELECT  @FirstName = FirstName 
FROM    tblUser 
WHERE   UserId=1;


SELECT  TOP (1) DocumentDate, Auto_FullText
FROM    tblDocuments
WHERE   CONTAINS(Auto_FullText, @FirstName);
```

Comment: Actually I am using 'View', so can't declare variables/parameters.

Comment: if its a view why cant you just hardcode the value for Firstname after all views are only used for static view of data. Consider using a stored procedure or multi statement table valued function if firstname on a given id can change.

Comment: Not a problem if this question helped you can accept it as an answer :)